# What is the correct way to fine-tune OpenAI LLM model using their API?

Tags: javascript, express, openai-api, large-language-model, fine-tuning

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

app.post("/firegpt", async (req, res) => {
  const { conversation } = req.body;

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

  app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));
  });

  let message = `I am FireGPT -  I know all about firefighting. I''m here to answer all of your questions about fire-fighting and what fire-fighters do.
`;

  conversation.forEach((msg) => {
    if (msg.role === "user") {
      message += `User: ${msg.message}\n`;
    } else if (msg.role === "assistant") {
      message += `${msg.message.replace("Fire DBT: ", "")}\n`; // <-- Updated line
    }
  });
  const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
    messages: [
      {
        role: "assistant",
        content: message,
      },
      {
        role: "user",
        content: "",
      },
    ],
    temperature: 1.3,
    max_tokens: 1131,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0.8,
    presence_penalty: 1.1,
  });
  res.json({
    message: "FireGPT: " + response.data.choices[0].message.content.trim(),
  });
});
```

Can I change the `let message` variable to JSON and just import as much data as I want or what would be the correct way to implement fine tuning given this backend express api? Having trouble with finding a good youtube and trouble with the DOCs, I'm a newer programmer

Thank you!